# Hostelworld cancellation after checkout

Tags: cancellations, fraud, hostelworld

I booked a stay at a property they Hostelworld, completed the stay (even adding extra night) and checkout as normal.

Several hours after checkout I get an email from Hostelworld

“As requested, your booking has been canceled. If you have any questions, please contact the property via email”

I never requested cancellation and suspect the property cancelled reservation on their side. Either to avoid paying Hostelworld their commission or to prevent me leaving a verified review for the property.

What steps can I take now? The email is directing me to contact the property, but if they are instigator in this I don’t expect must assistance from them. Hostelworld don’t seem to provide their own support for this scenario.

Comment: What are you worried about, or hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Hmm, just want the property to be playing fairly. Not cheating future guests out of legitimate reviews or scamming the Hostelworld platform. Nothing in it for me really.

Comment: I would suggest that HostelWorld has just as much of not more of an interest in that, and is much better-positioned to accomplish it than you are. I don’t think you have any real responsibilities to that goal beyond reporting the situation to them.

Comment: (With that said, I understand the impulse to see that justice is served 100%)

Comment: Is this a simple IT foul-up, or human foul-up? System should have sent a "thanks for staying" and instead sent a "confirming cancellation" letter? Apart from a frisson of unease I don't see a bad consequence for you, given that your stay is complete.

Comment: There's an email address for customer service. Send them an email telling them you actually completed your stay and if they ignore it (as they likely will) it's on them.